# Prevent vertical movement in Google Web VR View

Tags: virtual-reality, google-vr, webvr

Is there a way to fix the view of Google Web VR View so it doesn't go up and down. Currently I have an image with a floor inside a room. When you view it with an iPhone, it automatically points to the floor if you hold it normally in your hands and you would have no idea there was anything to look at above. No one would lift their phone and go "Ahhhhhhh"
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want the `is_yaw_only` option? https://developers.google.com/vr/develop/web/vrview-web#vr_view

Comment: Thanks Brian. Not sure how I missed this one :)